# SQL join puzzler

Tags: sql, join

Given

```
pricetable  
sym(k)   pricedate(k) price
msft     1/2/2009     33
msft     1/3/2009     34
msft     1/4/2009     35
ibm   1/2/2009       66
ibm   1/3/2009       65
ibm   1/4/2009       64
```

and

```
datestable
pricedate(k)
1/1/2009
1/2/2009
1/3/2009
1/4/2009
```

I would like to get this result set

```
sym pricedate price
msft 1/1/2009 null
msft 1/2/2009 33
msft 1/3/2009 34
msft 1/4/2009 35
ibm  1/1/2009  null
ibm  1/2/2009  66
ibm  1/3/2009  65
ibm  1/4/2009  64
```

This is a one-time dump, so I don't mind creating intermediate temporary tables if that'll get it done.

FWIW, I am not just dumping this problem on SO, I have tried a bunch of things, but can't get it to work.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.sym, b.pricedate, p.price 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT sym, pricedate
    FROM pricetable CROSS JOIN datestable
) b  /* base table */
LEFT JOIN pricetable p ON p.sym = b.sym AND p.pricedate = b.pricedate
ORDER BY b.pricedate, b.sym
```

Comment: Funny - the ORDER BY seems backward from the results shown in the question, and it also seems to need b.sym DESC!  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT syms.sym, pt.pricedate, syms.price FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT sym, datestable.priceDate FROM priceTable, datestable) syms 
     LEFT JOIN priceTable pt on pt.priceDate = syms.priceDate
```

should do it.

At least it works under SQL Server.

Comment: Ehh, it's how I think of cross joins in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Untested...key observation, you seem to need a row for each stock for each possible day.

```
SELECT k1.sym, k1,pricedate, k1.price
  FROM DatesTable JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(sym) FROM PriceTable) AS k1 ON 1 = 1
       LEFT JOIN Pricetable AS pt
                 ON (k1.pricedate = pt.pricedate AND k1.sym = pt.sym)
 ORDER BY k1.sym DESC, k1.pricedate;
```

An alternative to the 'JOIN ... ON 1 = 1' is 'CROSS JOIN':

```
SELECT k1.sym, k1,pricedate, k1.price
  FROM DatesTable CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(sym) FROM PriceTable) AS k1
       LEFT JOIN Pricetable AS pt
                 ON (k1.pricedate = pt.pricedate AND k1.sym = pt.sym)
 ORDER BY k1.sym DESC, k1.pricedate;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
DECLARE @pricetable TABLE (sym VARCHAR(10), pricedate DATETIME, price INT)
INSERT INTO @pricetable (sym, pricedate, price) VALUES('msft', '1/2/9', 33)
INSERT INTO @pricetable (sym, pricedate, price) VALUES('msft', '1/3/9', 34)
INSERT INTO @pricetable (sym, pricedate, price) VALUES('msft', '1/4/9', 35)
INSERT INTO @pricetable (sym, pricedate, price) VALUES('ibm', '1/2/9', 66)
INSERT INTO @pricetable (sym, pricedate, price) VALUES('ibm', '1/3/9', 65)
INSERT INTO @pricetable (sym, pricedate, price) VALUES('ibm', '1/4/9', 64)

DECLARE @datestable TABLE (pricedate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @datestable (pricedate) VALUES('1/1/9')
INSERT INTO @datestable (pricedate) VALUES('1/2/9')
INSERT INTO @datestable (pricedate) VALUES('1/3/9')
INSERT INTO @datestable (pricedate) VALUES('1/4/9')


SELECT AllDates.sym, AllDates.pricedate, outerp.price
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                d.pricedate, 
                p.sym
            FROM 
                @datestable AS d 
                CROSS JOIN @pricetable AS p
            GROUP BY 
                d.pricedate, 
                p.sym
        ) AllDates
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @pricetable AS outerp ON
            outerp.pricedate = AllDates.pricedate
            AND outerp.sym = AllDates.sym
ORDER BY AllDates.sym, AllDates.pricedate
```

Results:

```
sym        pricedate               price
---------- ----------------------- -----------
ibm        2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
ibm        2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 66
ibm        2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 65
ibm        2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 64
msft       2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
msft       2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 33
msft       2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 34
msft       2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 35
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
select a.sym, a.pricedate, p2.price
(select distinct p.sym, d.pricedate
from pricetable p
cross join
datestable d )a
left join pricetable p2
on a.sym = p2.sym and a.pricedate = p2.pricedate
```

or

select a.sym, a.pricedate, p2.price
    (select p.sym, d.pricedate
    from (select distinct sym from pricetable) p
    cross join
    datestable d )a
    left join pricetable p2
    on a.sym = p2.sym and a.pricedate = p2.pricedate

the cross join should get a complete list of syms and dates then by left joining tothe price table again you should get the rest of the column data for those records which havea price.

Comment: We have to hope the optimizer pushes the SELECT DISTINCT down to  PriceTable before doing the CROSS JOIN to avoid a large intermediate table.